# Generate a random unique ID using PHP

Tags: php, sql, random, unique

I have a table that is looks like this. This is some of the general information when a user registers on my site.

```
+------------+------------+
|   user_id  | username   |
|   312543   |   Bobby    |
|   543765   |  Victoria  |
+------------+------------+
```

I am just wondering, how would you generate a random **unique** number for `user_id`? Let’s say a number between 1 and 100 that is not yet in the database. I want to accomplish this using PHP, not SQL.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a unique ID using PHP?

Comment: Why not a simple `AUTO_INCREMENT` ? That would be the best bet. Random IDs are prone to repetition.

Comment: choose a random number in range, test if it is unique and if not repeat until it is BUT: make sure thera are an unused number in range

Comment: I just don't want the user_id itself in order

Comment: You're going to have to be a LOT more specific. Why don't you want them in order? Do you want to prevent people guessing at what might be a valid user id? (this has limited value as a security measure). How many records do you expect to have? How large a value (characters/digits) is appropriate? What contraints are there on the data type?

Answer (score 15):

Improving upon Niet the Dark Absol's answer: You can use `uniqid(rand())`. `uniqid()` will generate a number based on your server's internal clock and `rand()` will prefix it with a random number. So even if two users register in the same tiniest fraction, the `rand()` prefix will assign them a different prefix with over 99.99999% probability.

Comment: would concatenating timestamp to your method help resolve that tiniest fraction?

Answer (score 5):

You could use PHP's `uniqid` function. It's not random (it's based on the server's clock) but unless you have two people register in the same tiniest fraction of a second then it will be guaranteed to be unique and it's non-sequential.

Comment: I wouldn't call uniqid "non-sequential". Since it's based on the server clock each ID generated is higher than the previous one. It's non-incremental, but it still leaks information.

Comment: -1 because the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) states: This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value

Answer (score 3):

[PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) :

> Caution This function does not generate cryptographically secure
>   values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need
>   a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(),
>   random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.
>
> Warning This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value.
>   Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is
>   changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does
>   not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to
>   increase likelihood of uniqueness.

```
 uniqid ([ string $prefix = "" [, bool $more_entropy = FALSE ]] ) :
 string
```

In other words , if your script is running with parallel process , you risk to have the same unique id. so i can told you that there is no way to have 100%  unique id , but we can increase the probability like using other function like :
rand , and the **more_entropy** (the second parameter of uniqid)

```
 $unique = uniqid (rand(), true);
```

Don't forget that we are only increasing the probability to have unique id .

May be 99.99% uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I agree with @Shankar Damodaran, it is a lot better to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` rather than random IDs because if you start using random ones, then you might have to check first whether that random ID already exists and then choose another random one and check again till you finally get a unique one.

And if you really want it to be random, you can use the PHP's `rand` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function isUnique($var)
{
//we check here if var is unique, return TRUE on unique FALSE on non unique.
}

    //this is my function for generating random strings(can be used for numbers)
function _generateRandomString() {
    $chars = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));
    shuffle($chars);
    return implode(array_slice($chars, 0,25));
}

  //actual code: 
$string= _generateRandomString();
while(!isUnique($string)) //if string is unique, while loop stops.
 {
 $string= _generateRandomString();
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

With php u can make like this.

```
$pattern = "1234567890";
$ID = $pattern{rand(0,10)};
for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++)
{
    $ID .= $pattern{rand(0,10)};
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that will only ever generate **unique** values? I don't think so.

Comment: hint, it probably won't. 
This answer is half way there though, You still need to check against the database to make sure it's unique.